# Remmina 1.3.4 on Ubuntu - which is the HOST KEY?

Tags: remmina

I can't identify the right "HOST KEY" to do "copy and paste" with text.
Seems a dummy question but I tried all combinations.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm unable to escape from VMware vSphere client console pressing Ctrl+Alt.
>   A: You are probably pushing the Ctrl key on the right side of the keyboard. That key is reserved as Remmina Host key. Use the left Ctrl key or change the host key in the Remmina global settings.

From the [Remmina FAQ](https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-Usage-FAQ).

If you open preferences in Remmina, and go to keyboard, you can change the defaults:

[image: Remmina preferences]

(And honestly: [googling the phrase "remmina host key"](https://www.google.com/search?q=remmina+host+key) would probably give you the answer in less time than it took to write this question. Trying google before asking is always a good idea.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the info.
What I detected is:

a) must select a text to copy.
b) press left-ctrl and C to copy.
c) "click on another place"
d) press left-ctrl and V to paste...

Not really easy to discover I must click in another place and the PASTE can' t identify "paste it in the cursor site". (like other tools)

Anyway, thanks !